# react-image-gallery- how to change the sizes of image and not show full screen?

Tags: reactjs

How do I change the size of the images - length width, so that they don't show me all the width screen jast on half screen?

the code:

```
const images=[
    {
      original: "/image/out.jpg",sizes:"100%",
      thumbnail:"/image/out.jpg",
    },
    {
      original: "/image/ckitchen1.png",sizes:"100%",
      thumbnail:"/image/ckitchen1.png",
    },
    {
      original: "/image/ambut.jpg",sizes:"5vh",
      thumbnail:"/image/ambut.jpg",
    },
    {
      original: "/image/room.jpg",sizes:"5vh",
      thumbnail:"/image/room.jpg",
    },
    {
      original: "/image/salon.jpg",sizes:"5vh",
      thumbnail:"/image/salon.jpg",
    }
  ] 
    
    return <>   

        <div>
         <ImageGallery items={images} showIndex={true} />
         </div>
    </>
```